# Adding standard CA roots to busybox docker image

Tags: docker, busybox

I have a docker image based on busybox. It needs to make HTTPS requests to various public hosts (e.g. facebook API). But the connection fails, seemingly because there are no CA roots in the busybox image. I do not wish to mount any volumes from this docker container. How can I add certs to the busybox image? Or alternatively, is there a variant of the busybox image that comes with CA certs?

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you: https://www.whaletech.co/2014/07/22/ca-certificates-for-docker-busybox-containers.html

You can either mount the certificates:

```
docker run -v '/etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs' busybox ...
```

or create a Dockerfile and copy them inside your Docker image

Comment: Unfortunately this must be a completely isolated container; I cannot mount any volumes whatsover.

Comment: So, use the second solution, as stated in my answer : copy the certificates in the image, then start the container. Why downvote this answer, then ?